# tif output not generating from Ghostscript

Tags: vb.net, pdf, io, tiff, ghostscript

Want to generate .tif file from .pdf in VB using the Ghostscript parms below (layout is rough still learning different GS parms available).  No errors are returned, even when the -debug option is turned on.  GS prompts for each page, so appears that GS can read the input file.  Please let me know what should change to render output .tif:

'GS parm
         Dim gsInputFileName As String = (FilePath + FileName + ".pdf")
         Dim gsOutputFileName As String = (FilePath + FileName + ".tif")
         Dim gsArgs(0 To 5) As String
             gsArgs(4) = "-dDEBUG "
             gsArgs(0) = "-dSAFER "
             gsArgs(1) = "-sDevice=tiffg3 "   'Configure the output
             gsArgs(2) = "-r300 "        'Configure the output
             gsArgs(3) = "-sOUTPUTFILE="     'Set output files
             gsArgs(5) = gsOutputFileName   'Set output files

Dim args As String = (gsArgs(0) + gsArgs(1) + gsArgs(2) + gsArgs(4) + gsArgs(3) + gsArgs(5) + ", " + gsInputFileName)

```
        Dim Process As New Process()
        Process.StartInfo.FileName = gsScriptPath
        Process.StartInfo.Arguments = args
        Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        Process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
        Process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal

        Process.Start()

        Process.WaitForExit()
        If Process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = False Then
            Process.Close()
            gsReformatToTiff = True
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the arguments from the command line (have your basic program print out what it's sending as 'args' so you know what it *really* is). Does that work ?

It's impossible to infer from the code snippets what you are actually sending as a command line, and so it's not possible to tell you what is incorrect.

Oh, and don't use `-dSAFER`.

Comment: using the same parms from the command line works fine, no error and a .tif generates but in visual studio no error and no .tif.  I removed -dSAFER and had the same results.   From command line running gswin32 -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -r600x600 -sOutputFile="C:\TEMP\testgs_300.tif" "C:\TEMP\HMES.pdf"

Comment: in visual studio running gswin32 with the following parms: -sDevice=tiff4 -r600X600 -sOutputFile=c:\temp\HMES.tif c:\temp\HMES.pdf

Comment: I think that VB.NET sample you provided has comma (,) in the args... so, at the moment your args string looks something like: -sDevice=tiff4 -r600X600 -sOutputFile=c:\temp\HMES-out.tif, c:\temp\HMES-in.pdf. Try to replace ", " with " "

Comment: I also figured this was the case, which is why I said to have the VB program print out the arguments its using and then try those. Its pretty important to test the same thing as the app generates :-) Notice for example that the command line you say you ran has -sDEVICE, while the VB code clearly has -sDevice. The GS command line is sensitive to case. Make *absolutely* certain that your VB app is executing the command you think it is, have it print out what its using rather than executing it, and compare *very carefully* with the working command line.